# Pivot data to Multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, count

I am trying to solve a [question on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations/problem).

Here is my approach to solve the question:

```
select Concat(Name, '(', Substring(Occupation,1,1), ')') as pr
from Occupations
order by name;

select Concat('There are a total of',' ', count(*),' ',Occupation, 's.') as pr
from Occupations
group by Occupation
order by pr
```

This is the sample output of my query:

```
Ashely(P)
Christeen(P)
Jane(A)
Jenny(D)
Julia(A)
Ketty(P)
Maria(A)
Meera(S)
Priya(S)
Samantha(D)
There are a total of 2 doctors.
There are a total of 2 singers.
There are a total of 3 actors.
There are a total of 3 professors.
```

Why couldn't my code generate expected output?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a good description. Describe what it does do. Include the actual SQL implementation and version in your question. Not all are the same.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the given question, you would need to create columns from the records in the table, but, SQL doesn't have a native PIVOT function like some other technologies, though we can simulate it. Here's one way to pivot our data:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Doctor' THEN Name ELSE NULL END) AS Doctor,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Professor' THEN Name ELSE NULL END) AS Professor,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Singer' THEN Name ELSE NULL END) AS Singer,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Actor' THEN Name ELSE NULL END) AS Actor
FROM
    (SELECT Name, Occupation, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) AS rn
     FROM Occupations) AS sub
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY rn;
```

The code you've written serves a different purpose than the task of pivoting the table as described in the question.

Comment: **[Look AI-Generated to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)**

Comment: It's not AI-generated. It's the same solution I got when I practiced on HackerRank.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of solving a problem was good. You can use this approach and it works in mysql but it doesn't work in oracle.
Because, in Oracle, CONCAT function can take a maximum of 2 arguments to concatenate where as in mysql, CONCAT function can take multiple arguments.
You can use nested concat statements as follows:

select concat(concat('There are a total of ', count(*)), concat(' ', occupation)) as pr
from occupations
group by occupation
order by pr;

Else, use || to concat multiple strings as below:

select ('There are a total of '|| count(*) || ' ' || occupation || 's') as pr
from occupations
group by occupation
order by pr;

Comment: IN MYSQL || is logical or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add only [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)  function

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat(Name, '(', Substring(Occupation, 1, 1), ')') SEPARATOR ' ') pr FROM Occupations; 

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Concat('There are a total of ', cnt,' ', Occupation, '.') SEPARATOR ' ') pr FROM (
    SELECT Occupation, count(*) cnt FROM Occupations GROUP BY Occupation
) t
```

Try it here https://dbfiddle.uk/5dNfq0Ch